# Program in c to check digits and uppercase letters not working

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program in c that checks if the input entered contains an upper case letter in it and a number in it. If so it outputs that the input is good and if the input only contains an upper case or a only a number or none it outputs that it is bad.But when I run the code and input an input with only a number in it, it still outputs that the input is good.Here is my code can anyone point out what is causing this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>


int main()
{

   int uppercase, digit = 0;
   int i;
   char pass [100];

   printf("Please input a password\n");
   scanf(" %s", pass);

   for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
   {
            if(isupper(pass[i])){uppercase = 1;}
            if(isdigit(pass[i])){digit = 1;}
   }

    if(uppercase==1  && digit==1){printf("Your password is good!");
    }else{printf("Your password sucks");}


    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=100;i++)` you check 100 characters, even if the password is shorter.

Comment: Yes because I don't know how long the input will be but probably less than 100

Comment: if the password is empty (0 characters), but `pass[50]` contains a digit and `pass[95]` contains an uppercase character, you output that the password is good.

Comment: `man strlen`. And don't ... EVER ... use `scanf("%s"...)` -> buffer overflow ahead! This is kind of *ironic* when you try to deal with passwords... (you don't need formatting here, use `fgets(pass, 100, stdin)` in this case)

Comment: Initialize variable `uppercase` with 0 during declaration like `digit` variable.

Comment: @Wimmel: 101 characters with the last being _undefined behaviour_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating `char pass [100]` as an automatic local variable. This means that it will be placed in the function's stack frame. Variables allocated this way are not initialized to any particular value, their contents in undefined.

If you type in the password 'test' you will have

```
pass[0] == 't'
pass[1] == 'e'
pass[2] == 's'
pass[3] == 't'
pass[4] == '\0'
pass[5] == ????
```

`pass[5]` can be any value, including an uppercase or digit. Your 'for' loop is reading these uninitialized values and giving the wrong result.

To resolve this, have your for loop stop when it hit's the '\0' or 'null' character.

```
for(i=0;pass[i]!='\0';i++)
```

This code will expose a security vulnerability if the password is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int uppercase = 0, digit = 0, i;
    char pass[100];
    printf("Please input a password\n");
    scanf("%s", pass);
    for (i = 0; pass[i]; ++i) {
        if (isupper(pass[i])) uppercase = 1;
        if (isdigit(pass[i])) digit = 1;
    }
    if (uppercase && digit) printf("Your password is good!");
    else printf("Your password sucks");
    return 0;
}
```